# How to add workloads in Visual Studio 2017 Mac?

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio, wcf, visual-studio-mac

I'm trying to create a new WCF Application Service, to do that I have to add new workloads: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/modify-visual-studio.

But I only have [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PhBS.jpg) when I run the installer on Mac, is it possible to create WCF project on Mac via Visual Studio?

Comment: WCF development is only supported on Windows.